# SQL SELECT DISTINCT and GROUP BY both produce duplicates

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I have a decent size table with 20+ columns and almost 3 million rows, and I want to select all the unique values from a single column and enter them into a newly created table. After research, I have attempted this using both the DISTINCT and GROUP BY approaches, but both are producing duplicate values. Furthermore, I've set the new column in the new table as a Primary Key, which I don't believe should allow duplicate values.

I'm definitely a beginner here, so perhaps there is something simple I'm doing wrong. Here's some sample code:

Using GROUP BY

```
INSERT INTO ResourceGroups(ResourceGroup)
SELECT ResourceGroup
FROM dbo.UsageData
WHERE ResourceGroup IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ResourceGroup
```

Using DISTINCT

```
INSERT INTO ResourceGroups(ResourceGroup)
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceGroup
FROM dbo.UsageData
WHERE ResourceGroup IS NOT NULL
```

The results of both of these seem to be the same. Here's a sample of the first few rows:

```
ResourceGroup

aiiInnovationTime
Api-Default-Central-US
Api-Default-Central-US
applicationinsights
applicationinsights
azurefunctions-southeastasia
azurefunctions-southeastasia
```

The query resulted in 532 rows, and it clearly eliminated some duplicates after consolidating down from 3 million. However, there are obviously still duplicates here, and they also successfully inserted into a primary key column which shouldn't allow duplicate. Furthermore there's a blank row despite my attempt to filter out NULLs (though maybe there's a space or something there?). Needless to say, I'm a bit confused about what I'm doing wrong, and would greatly appreciate any help that this community can provide!

Comment: For the duplicate values you can check leading and/or trailing spaces.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `INSERT INTO` line and just run the `SELECT` (in either of the cases)? What rows do you get back? Are they what you expected? (The first probably failed because you have no aggregate function in your SELECT. What does the second show you?)

Comment: Tip of today: Use GROUP BY when aggregate functions are involved, otherwise use SELECT DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are spaces in your data

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ResourceGroup, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ' ... '), 
         CHAR(10) + CHAR(13), ' ... '), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ... ')
    FROM dbo.UsageData
    WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(ResourceGroup)) IS NOT NULL
```

LTRIM trims leading spaces and RTRIM trims trailing spaces. Try this out and see if it works!

Comment: (sorry if you are getting spammed with comment notifications, I'm new to this and am trying to make the formatting readable). TL;DR, the query didn't work, but I think I discovered why. I opened the results in Notepad++ and found that the duplicate values seem to have differentiations in unseen characters. It looks like this:

    "Api-Default-Central-US[CR]
    "[CR][LF]
    Api-Default-Central-US[CR][LF]

So one value has a set of quotes and an extra carriage return while the second seemingly duplicate value has no quotes and a single set of [CR][LF]. How do I account for this?

Comment: This seems to have exposed an issue in my source data where older data only has quotes around select values that require it whereas the newer data has quotes around every value. So now I need to figure out how to standardize all that.

Comment: I am trying a replace and see if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Both the queries you mentioned should give you unique results, the anomaly however, is due to may be leading or trailing white-spaces.

Depending on the DB you can modify the query for e.g.

**For Oracle DB**: You can use `TRIM` function which removes both leading and trailing white-spaces.

**SQL Server** Don't have single function you have to use `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` to remove spaces.

Answer (score -1):

As Chetan Ranpariya mentioned, checked leading and trailing spaces. The way you do it depends on the SQL engine. For instance, in MySQL you can use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim.